# Is there a pattern or recommended way of waiting on a generic value to achieve a certain value?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In this brave new async world, I find myself time and time again in need of an awaitable method to wait for something to be at a certain state or meet a certain condition. For example (pseudocode)

`await (myStateMachine.State == StateEnum.Ready);`

`await (myDownloadProgress == 100.0);`

`await (mySpiDeviceFifoLEvel != 0);`

These scenarios arise because I need to hold off some asynchronously started code until a certain state is achieved in another part of the code. For example, the user fires up new part of the UI, but a background thread is still trying to establish communications with a piece of hardware. Or the state machine controlling one piece of hardware needs to wait until another state machine controlling another piece of hardware has got to a certain state of readiness.

I have come up with mainly wonderful and wacky ways of achieving this, and in doing so noticed certain patterns emerging, so the natural progression is to code us some helper class / generic to do this sort of behaviour in a re-usable fashion.

Before I go down this route, there must be others addressing this sort of issue, so I was interested if anyone knows of a tried and tested pattern or recommended way of doing this. I have done some searching on the WWW but not found anything particularly conclusive. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242129/async-pattern-waiting-for-an-event-before-returning-some-value-from-a-method) touches on the subject but the op is asking for a different reason. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748328/wait-for-a-task-or-tasks-to-reach-certain-milestone-the-async-await-way) asks for the same sort of thing but specific to task progress.

## Ways I have achieved this so far

### 1. Don't do it! Use an event

When I am in control of the source (e.g. a state machine's state) that is changing, I often convince myself that I'm doing it wrong, and instead of waiting for a value to be achieved, I should make the producer (state machine) generate an event when my condition is achieved. Any listener can then use an `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` to wait on the handler

```
{
  myStateMachine.OnMyConditionAchieved += OnConditionAchievedEventHandler;
  myEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  myEvent.WaitOne();
}

void OnConditionAchievedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myEvent.Set();
}
```

The downside of this is that I don't really want to litter my producer code with events that are specific to the consumers needs.

### 2. Use an Event, coding overhead vs performance tradeoff

If there isn't already a handy event to hook into (1), then the producer is forever being modified to meet the needs of the consumers. So the obvious natural progression is to make use of something like `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern. That way, there is no endless extension to the producers and the consumer does this:

```
void StateMachine_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Property == "State")
  {
    if (myStateMachine.State == State.TheStateThatIWant)
    {
      myEvent.Set();
    }
  }
}
```

This feels like a win because I use the NotifyPropertyChanged system a lot - it's required for DataBinding, so there's less code to add, but, it feels dirty that we're listening to every change in the producer in order to filter out the condition that want - surely there's a better way?!

### 3. Use a Task and poll (ugh)

Spin up a task that checks state and sleeps if a condition is not met indefinitely or until the task is cancelled. Callers, then wait on the task to complete. Task completes when the condition is met or cancelled.

Pros - makes for neat code, esp when using Task.Run(() => … ) lambda approach, can take advantage of task cancellation techniques (tokens, timeouts etc) which is often also needed
Cons - polling feels dirty, seems a bit heavy handed to built a whole new Task to do such a simple job

### 4. Use a task and wait on event

Better than polling right? But suffers from the same issue as 1) and 2) of needing an appropriate event to hook to, so 2) (INotifyPropertyChanged) more common than 1). So the implementation often ends up as spin up a task, wait on ManualResetEvent, listen to PropertyChanged and filter changes, fire event, return from task.

### 5. The holy grail

I'm not 100% sure but something that is
1) lightweight
2) allows the condition to be specified at the time the wait is initiated
3) not going to be a huge resource burden if 10,000 things were waiting on various properties to achieve certain values
4) clean i.e. disposes of resources correctly

```
MagicValueWaiter waitForValue = new MagicValueWaiter(MyStateMachine, nameof(State), (s) => (s > 4) && (s < 8));
await waitForInit.WaitAsync();
```

or

```
await ValueWaiter.WaitAsync(MyObject, nameof(MyPropertyorField), (s) => (s == States.Init);
```

So basically, a generic class / method for waiting for a given property or field of a given object to meet a certain given condition in the form of a lambda returning bool.

This approach might at first glance suggest a polling technique, however, if I forced MyObject to conform to something like must implement INotifyPropertyChanged or some custom base class to support this behaviour e.g. ISupportValueWaiting then we could hook into some common bahaviour e.g. events on MyObject and avoid polling.

Any obvious solutions I'm missing? Anyone got any novel ideas on how to do this? or comments on mine?

Comment: Have you come across [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Have you looked at TaskCompletionSource?

Comment: I have used TaskCompleteSource, but primarily to return a value back to an waiting method so I didn't immediately see how it applies to this problem, thinking about it more carefully, I see that a producer could SetResult(null) on a TCS supplied by the consumer, which would give us the await consumer and release in producer behaviour required. It requires that the producer support 'ICanReleaseConsumers' behaviour and supporting arbitrary conditions requires some thought, but I imagine there is also a way to build in the lambda condition - I'll have a play - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is using a `TaskCompletionSource` and the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` to complete a `Task` as soon some condition on the `obj` is met.

So:

```cs
public static class ConditionWaiter
{
    public static Task WaitForAsync<T>(this T obj, string PropertyName, Func<T, bool> pred)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        obj = obj ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        PropertyName = PropertyName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(PropertyName));
        pred = pred ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pred));

        var taskCompletionsource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        void handler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == PropertyName && pred(obj))
            {
                obj.PropertyChanged -= handler;
                taskCompletionsource.SetResult(true);
            }
        }

        obj.PropertyChanged += handler;

        return taskCompletionsource.Task;
    }
}
```

And you could use it like:

```cs
await someValue.WaitForAsync(nameof(SomeType.SomeProperty), s => ...);
```

Comment: Thank you! After comments from canton7 and Sean above, I put something together with TCS this afternoon which ended up not dissimilar from your answer but yours has some improvements and looks neater so I'm going to merge them, test and check it all works.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive).

Comment: Yes, Looks like exactly what I need - nice to see a mature 3rd party offering available. Might take me a while to get my head into it but looks quite powerful. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It's not 3d party. `IObservable` is part of the ,NET Framework and reactive extensions were created inside Microsoft.

Comment: My bad, I followed your link to github, then to http://reactivex.io/ and read 'collection of open source projects' and incorrectly assumed this must be outside MSFT! Sorry! I am so out of date :/

Comment: Just setting the record straight. There's nothing wrong in being from Microsoft or not. Microsoft has a long history of open source and free libraries.

Comment: Totally agree, and I hope my comments didn't cause any offense, there was none intended. I am a big MSFT fan, love the technologies, just a little overwhelming keeping up to speed on everything. I had no understanding of the relationship between reactive.io and MSFT and I jumped to the wrong conclusion when I skim read the site :) Lesson learned!